# 2.3.0 store not found while reindex

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:20
>
> The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try
>   again.
>
> The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try
>   again.

When i try to reindex - getting this notice. What does it means?

Comment: When i try to open Catalog -> Categories, i'm getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Check index, which going before notice. Find this module and his tables, find fields like "store_id" or "website_ids" and remove non-exist id.

Comment: "which going after last index item"